# Apple Configurator config files in Intune

Tags: sccm, microsoft-intune

I’m looking at moving a MDM config from SCCM hybrid to Intune Standalone. I know I can migrate but right now I’m running down options for a fresh setup.

If all I have is an xml dump of an Apple Configuator plist/xml output, can I use that “as is” in an Intune custom profile? I know that ideally I’d generate a new file in Apple Configurator 2 but is it *required*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can import the file directly, though in reality Intune directly supports the features that previously needed to be managed this way, so it's probably a good idea to just re-create the rules.